# Is it possible to change application state or delete preserved state of app after press home button

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios5

In application i want such situation like. When my application goes into background it store current state. At server side have some update and i want to start my application with those new data.

My issue is for few second I see old preserved state of application.
Is it possible to start application from

```
- (void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

to

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Comment: Can't you use `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` to get the state and then store it/send a request to the server?

Comment: What is your question? Usually a question ends with question mark ' ? ' :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` to get the state and then store it/send a request to the server right when your app moves to the background. Then, in your app delegate or in your first view's viewDidLoad, you can query your database to get the latest state and respond appropriately.